# How to make a bootable SD-Card image containing various images?

Tags: embedded-linux

Am stuck in making a bootable SD-Card.

I have gpt_both0.bin, hyp.mbn, NON-HLOS.bin, rpm.mbn, sbl1.mbn, sec.dat, tz.mbn, emmc_appsboot.mbn, boot.img and rootfs.img files.

When i flash all of 'em into eMMC (using fastboot command) the board boots easily and we dont face any problems. But now i also have to make a bootable SD-Card to boot board via SD-card.

Can anyone please explain how can i achieve this !

I am using Ubuntu-14.04 on my PC.

Comment: Have you tried flashing the bootloader files to your SD card?